# cardinal of a quotient space

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, equivalence-relations

Suppose that we have an equivalence relation $R$ defined on an infinite set $X$ and that all equivalence classes are finite. Is it so that the cardinal of the quotient space of $R$ is that of $X$? If so, I would appreciate a proof. If not, a counterexample.

Comment: @Martin: Are we back on the [cardinality] tag issue?

Comment: @Asaf: Sorry, I should have been more careful when retagging.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its true. Suppose $\{X_i\}_I$ is a partition of $X$ defined by this equivalence relation (i.e. equivalence classes). $X=\bigcup X_i$. If $Card(X)\ge \aleph_0$ and $Card(X_i)<\aleph_0$ then $Card(X)=Card(\bigcup X_i)\le Card(I)\cdot Card(\aleph_0)\le Card(I)\cdot Card(I)=Card(I)$.

As it was pointed out in comments to get inequality $Card(I)\le Card(X)$ we can define injection from $f:I\rightarrow X$ using axiom of choice. For any $i\in I$ pick (using AC) element $x_i\in X_i$ and set $f(i)=x_i$. This function is injective because $X_i\cap X_j=\emptyset$ for any $i\neq j$.

Now by Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem we get $Card(X)=Card(I)$.

Comment: Perhaps you should say something about the reverse inequality as well.  (It's not completely trivial, in the sense that some kind of choice principle is necessary to prove it.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the axiom of choice holds, every partition of an infinite set into finite sets must have the same cardinality. The reason is that if $\mathcal A=\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint sets, then $$\left|\bigcup\mathcal A\right|=\sup\left\{|A_i|\vphantom{x^2}\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} i\in I\right\}\cdot|I|=\max\left\{\sup\left\{|A_i|\vphantom{x^2}\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} i\in I\right\},|I|\right\}$$

Assuming the $A_i$ are all finite, then we that becomes at most $\aleph_0\cdot|I|=|I|$ since $I$ is infinite.

---

Not assuming the axiom of choice, the plot like a slowly cooking gravy, thickens. It is possible in the absence of the axiom of choice to have a set and a partition of that set into strictly more parts than elements; or an incomparable cardinality of parts. Even if the parts themselves are finite!